# Jquery : Append querystring to all links

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to append a query string onto all dynamic links within a page - to fix a bug in a old release - is this possible?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 49):

Something like this?

```
var querystring = 'myquerystringtoadd';

$('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href) {
        href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    }
});
```

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ8hA/4/)

Comment: Better than @woz answer, because of the checking for existing querystring and either appending with & or prefixing with ?

Comment: @jaygooby. Yes. An additional check should also be made for url anchors ("#").

Comment: @flem -1: this does not work. I think it should be `href.match(/\?/)`.

Comment: @dalbaeb Nice spot. The `?` wasn't escaped. I've corrected the post and added a working fiddle. Thanks! If you're happy now, please remove the downvote :)

Comment: The only issue I came across with this is when an `a` tag didn't have an href property, so I just added `if(href) { href+= ...` into the mix to stop it from breaking on links like this.

Comment: @Novocaine88 Thanks for the comment. I've updated the code to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This solution with native javascript :

```
var querystring = 'yourQueryStringHere=;-)';

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    var x = e.originalTarget;
    if (x.nodeName === 'A') {

        var href = x.getAttribute('href');

        if(href) {
            href += (/\?/.test(href) ? '&' : '?') + querystring;
            x.setAttribute('href', href);
        }
    }

}, false);
```